# Match second number that follows a given pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have strings of this kind

```
hello 45 blabla 12 100 code 45 13 093bb
```

I'd like to match the second number that follows the keyword `code` (with Python). In this example `"13"` should be returned.

---

Here is the solution I found

```
s = "hello 45 blabla 12 100 code 45 13 093bb "
re.search("code \d+ \d+",s).group(0).split(" ")[-1]
# '13'
```

It works but there are probably better solutions. I have tried using lookbehind but I run into the issue that python doesn't tolerate lookbehind of underfined length (and I don't know the number of digits in the first number that follows `code`). I tried that

```
re.search("(?<=code \d+)\d+",s).group(0)
# raise error, v # invalid expression
# sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could skip `re` all together

```
>>> a = s.split()
>>> a[a.index('code') + 2]
'13'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it slightly cleaner by putting the desired value into a group.

```
>>> re.search("code \d+ (\d+)",s).group(1)
'13'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
re.search("code \d+ (\d+)", s).group(1)
```

should work. 
The () brackets identify which group you want to capture.
Group 0 is the whole text and the following are the groups numbered in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little shorter than the `re.search` solutions:

```
re.findall('code \d+ (\d+)', s)
```

It will return back only what matches the group defined in the `()`